# imagepng, set quality without writing to file, how?

Tags: php

I want to export a PNG into the memory:

```
imagepng ($img, ?, 9);
```

I want a good compress, but I need to then set a filename too. I dont want it, how to do it then?

Comment: with BASIC, its possible to do something "proc (1, 2, , , , 5);" but in Php....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
imagepng($img, null, 9, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php):

> filename: 
>     The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.